# Including javascript files

Tags: javascript, html

I'm finishing my project right now and see that I've got a lot of javascript code on each page. It's not included as a ".js" file, but rather coded in the page itself. I figured it's a bad idea, so now I'm trying to put them all in one .js file and include it in each page.

The only problem I'm facing now is this: Some functions are only called on certain pages and are depending on the inclusion of jquery plugins. Not all pages needs the plugin however.

Example:
On the home page I need to chain the Country dropbox with the City dropbox, thus I need the jchained.js plugin for jquery. The code I need to use is:

```
$(function(){
    $("#city").chained("#country");
});
```

When I add this function to the .js file, and I open a page where I don't need to chain the dropboxes I get logically an error:

> TypeError: $("#city").chained is not a function

So if I understand this correctly, in order to use a .js file with all my different functions for different plugins, I need to include all the plugins to all the pages?

Thanks for your ideas & help.

Comment: Why don't you split the functions into several files? Putting the JQuery-dependent code in a single file and the rest elsewhere would let you avoid the errors. Perhaps even more granularity would be nice. It depends on how much code you have and how it's written.

Comment: @Tom: Wouldn't that make a lot of ".js" files? I'll need for every function a separated file and I've got a lot of functions for different plugins.

Comment: I don't know, I haven't seen the code. It shouldn't be a problem if you remember about separation of concerns. If it is, the JS probably needs massive refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I don't think you should worry about including alot of .js files, that's part of web development. Another option, albeit slightly more tedious, is you can make a check for the function to exist (if the plugin .js has been included) and then call it if it does:

```
if(typeof yourFunctionName == 'function') {
    yourFunctionName();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the "not worrying about including a lot of .js files" part. More separate JS files means more requests - that means slower page loading, especially on bandwidth-limited devices (like mobile). I'd concatenate all of those JS files into one for the production environment, to make only one request necessary. I'd minify that file, too.

Comment: @ilollar: Exactly my point. But I'll need to include all the used plugins on all my pages if I'm going to use only one file.

Comment: @moonwalker Yes, but if it is only one concatenated and minified JS files for all of the pages, then it'll be cached after the first page load, and not really a worry for the rest of them. Or, you could make a main JS file for each page, separate out shared functionality into other JS files, and use something like [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) to "require" the necessary code in each main page JS.

Comment: My friend Ian is correct. Concatenation and minification is probably your best option, as it should significantly decrease the load time and requests made.

Comment: @ilollar: Ok now I get it. Thanks a lot. I'm going to do just that. :)

Answer (score 1):

It completely depends on how the code is structured or how complex the current code is.

An immediate solution will be,

1. Give an id to each page (may be on body tag).
2. Put all the code in a single external JavaScript file.
3. Execute the code meant for that particular page only if it has required id on that body element.
   Something like :

   if ( $('body').attr('id') == "home" ) { 
      /* Add home page JS here */
   }

You can try this.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Good idea. But I will have to go for the answer given by Sean. Thanks for your help!